# Android Writing Logs to text File

Tags: android

I'm Trying to Write Logs to Custom Log.txt File on Android File using this code of Mine but then this method creates file but contains nothing. Basically I want to read previous contents of the file and then append my data with the existing content.

The Code is as follows :

```
public static void write(String str) 
    {
        InputStream fileInputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutpurStream = null;
        try
        { 
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileOutpurStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                int ch = 0;
                int current = 0;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while((ch = fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
                {
                    buffer.append((char) ch);
                    current++;
                }
                byte data[]=new byte[(int)file.length()];
                fileInputStream.read(data);   
                fileOutpurStream.write(data);
                fileOutpurStream.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
                fileOutpurStream.flush();
            } 
            else
            {   
                file.createNewFile();
                fileOutpurStream.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
                fileOutpurStream.flush();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fileInputStream.close();
                fileOutpurStream.flush();
                fileOutpurStream.close();
                fileOutpurStream = null;
                fileInputStream = null;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Hope this can help...

```
public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add permission for writing_external_storage in Manifest!

Comment: I was need to add buf.flush(); beforebuf.close(); but tjis function was exactly what was I needing. thanks

Comment: from where should i call this function so it write all application's log in file???

Comment: I am downloading a file and want to log each progress till the download finishes. Is it OK to call this function 100 times in about 3 mins?

Comment: I would recommend restructuring the code so that `buf.close()` is inside a `finally` block.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamPrice for the buf.close() into a finally block.. for the rest, it's a very good solution. ;)

Comment: The result of `createNewFile()` is ignored. You might want to check for the result. Just nitpicking.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` was what @virusss8 meant, of course.

Comment: In case you want the system to properly do closing use try-with-resources:
`try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true))) { ... }`

Comment: trying to write to "sdcard/log.file" path results in permission denied even though manifest file is correct. Had to use context.getFilesDir() instead

Comment: Does this work for internal storage as well or only external?

Comment: @vaibhavS yes it should be just `File logFile = getFilesDir();`

Comment: So what was wrong with the OP's way?

Comment: @Matthieu he's hardcoding the file path, bad practice  specially nowadays with scoped storage

Answer (score 33):

For those new to Java logging in general and Android logging

1. [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) is generic java logging implementation and is now a project of
   Apache software foundation. It is not Android specific and so has
   some incompatibilities with Android.
2. SL4J is not a logging implementation, It is  an abstraction layer. It
   helps avoid a situations like, each 3rd party library 
   dependencies to a project, trying to using its own logging
   implementation like Log4j. [Source](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/108686).

Some options for logging to txt in Android are below

1. Use `logcat -f` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389217/1180117) to log to file. Note that from
   Android 4.2, READ_LOGS permission doesn't have any impact and every
   Application (unless phone is rooted) could only read its own logs.
   The  disadvantage here is logcat buffer is circular and has a size
   limit. You might not get earlier logs.
2. Use [microlog4android](https://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/) ( written for mobile devices like Android ) as
   in earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13479675/1180117). There could be a way, but I couldn't figure, how
   to use microlog4Android for logging to application internal storage.
   Only option for logs path was external storage like sdcard and so I
   couldn't use it.
3. Use [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) with [android-logging-log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). What does
   android-logging-log4j do ? It makes Log4j easier to use in Android
   by giving two functions.

   - option to send logs to logcat in addition to logging file
   - a simple way to set Log4j configuration options like file path, max file size, number of backups etc by providing LogConfigurator class.

   Simple example below. Notice that `logger` object in below example is a Log4j object returned and not an android-logging-log4j class. So android-logging-log4j is used only for configuring Log4j.
4. Yet to try [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html). LogBack is developed by same person who
   came up with Log4J 1.x and SL4J libraries. Not related to Log4j 2.x
   though.

**Steps for using Log4j in Android.**

1. Add both [log4j-1.2.x.jar](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) and [android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) to
   the libs folder.
2. Add permissions only if using external storage
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
3. Write `Log4j` helper class

   ```
   package com.example.logger;

   import android.os.Environment;
   import de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator;

   public class Log4jHelper {
       private final static LogConfigurator mLogConfigrator = new LogConfigurator();

       static {
           configureLog4j();
       }

       private static void configureLog4j() {
           String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "log4j.log";
           String filePattern = "%d - [%c] - %p : %m%n";
           int maxBackupSize = 10;
           long maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024;

           configure( fileName, filePattern, maxBackupSize, maxFileSize );
       }

       private static void configure( String fileName, String filePattern, int maxBackupSize, long maxFileSize ) {
           mLogConfigrator.setFileName( fileName );
           mLogConfigrator.setMaxFileSize( maxFileSize );
           mLogConfigrator.setFilePattern(filePattern);
           mLogConfigrator.setMaxBackupSize(maxBackupSize);
           mLogConfigrator.setUseLogCatAppender(true);
           mLogConfigrator.configure();

       }

       public static org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger( String name ) {
           org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger( name );
           return logger;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In Activity class

   ```
   org.apache.log4j.Logger log= Log4jHelper.getLogger( "YourActivity" );
   log.error("Error");
   log.info("Info");
   log.warn("Warn");
   ```

[Example Source](http://muratonnet.blogspot.in/2013/08/use-log4j-in-android.html). Note that, log4j 2.x ( improved functionalities ) rewritten from scratch is not backward comptible with log4j 1.x. So you have to use log4j 1.2.x jar with android-logging-log4j jar. I was able to log to application internal file and later email the file with `setReadable(true, false)`

Answer (score 26):

microlog4android works for me but the documentation is pretty poor. All they need to add is a this is a quick start [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/).

Here is a quick tutorial I found.

1. Add the following static variable in your main Activity:

   ```
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
   ```
2. Add the following to your `onCreate()` method:

   ```
   PropertyConfigurator.getConfigurator(this).configure();
   ```
3. Create a file named `microlog.properties` and store it in `assets` directory
4. Edit the `microlog.properties` file as follows:

   ```
   microlog.level=DEBUG
   microlog.appender=LogCatAppender;FileAppender
   microlog.formatter=PatternFormatter
   microlog.formatter.PatternFormatter.pattern=%c [%P] %m %T
   ```
5. Add logging statements like this:

   ```
   logger.debug("M4A");
   ```

For each class you create a logger object as specified in 1)

6.You may be add the following permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is the [source](http://bluegray-javalearning.blogspot.com/2011/06/use-microlog4j-in-android.html) for tutorial

Comment: FileAppender will create a file "microlog.txt" on your sdcard (full path in my case is "/sdcard/microlog.txt).

Comment: This quick tutorial should be part of the Microlog4Android official documentation.

Comment: Error:Android Dex: [project] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/code/microlog4android/Level; ?

Answer (score 11):

Warning: I may be totally misunderstanding you, but if all you want is a log file, why sweat?

Put this in a bat file (change the path to your tools directory, and  yourappname is of course your app's name):

```
cd "C:\devAndroid\Software\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\tools"
adb logcat -v time   ActivityManager:W  yourappname:D  *:W >"C:\devAndroid\log\yourappname.log"
```

Then in your code just do something similar to this:

```
Log.d("yourappname", "Your message");
```

To create the log, connect the USB cable and run your bat file.

Regards

Comment: Don't forget importing android.util.Log.

Comment: It returns "error: more than one device and emulator
- waiting for device -" and nothing more. Have something wrong?

Comment: How does this work if you're not near a PC while running the application?

Comment: @DDSports it doesn't. But he didn't understand the essence of question

Comment: @DDSports you can use adb over wifi.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem with following piece of code in command line way:

```
File outputFile = new File("pathToFile"); 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath())
```

Where "time" option adds metadata field details for date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the process issuing the message.

Then in your code just do something similar to this (using android.util.Log):

```
Log.d("yourappname", "Your message");
```

Comment: Works nicely when `adb` is connected, but does not work when the device is in standalone mode. I would not use it in production, but it is a simple solution in debug mode.

Answer (score 8):

Use [slf4android](https://github.com/bright/slf4android) lib. 
It's simple implementation of [slf4j api](http://www.slf4j.org/) using android java.util.logging.*.

Features:

- logging to file out of the box
- logging to any other destination by `LoggerConfiguration.configuration().addHandlerToLogger`
- shake your device to send logs with screenshot via email
- really small, it tooks only ~55kB

slf4android is maintained mainly by [@miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol).

Read more about slf4android on our blog:

- [Introducing slf4android](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/introducing-slf4android/)
- [Integrate slf4android with Crashlytics](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/integrate-slf4j-with-crashlytics/)

Answer (score 8):

After long time of investigation I found that:

- `android.util.Log` by default use `java.util.logging.Logger`
- LogCat uses `logger` with name `""`, to get instance of it use `LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("")`
- Android Devices adds to LogCat `logger` instance of `com.android.internal.logging.AndroidHandler` after run of debug apps
- But!!! `com.android.internal.logging.AndroidHandler` prints messages to logcat only with levels more then `java.util.logging.Level.INFO` such as (`Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, Level.SEVERE, Level.OFF`)

So to write logs to file just simple to the `rootLogger` `""`  add a `java.util.logging.FileHandler`:

```
  class App : Application{
    override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      Log.d(TAG, printLoggers("before setup"))

      val rootLogger = java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("")
      val dirFile = destinationFolder
      val file = File(dirFile,"logFile.txt")
      val handler = java.util.logging.FileHandler(file.absolutePath, 5* 1024 * 1024/*5Mb*/, 1, true)
      handler.formatter = AndroidLogFormatter(filePath = file.absolutePath)

      rootLogger?.addHandler(handler)

      Log.d(TAG, printLoggers("after setup"))
    }
  }

val destinationFolder: File
        get() {
            val parent = 
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absoluteFile
            val destinationFolder = File(parent, "MyApp")
            if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {
                destinationFolder.mkdirs()
                destinationFolder.mkdir()
            }
            return destinationFolder
        }
```

```
class AndroidLogFormatter(val filePath: String = "", var tagPrefix: String = "") : Formatter() {

    override fun format(record: LogRecord): String {
        val tag = record.getTag(tagPrefix)
        val date = record.getDate()
        val level = record.getLogCatLevel()
        val message = record.getLogCatMessage()
        return "$date $level$tag: $message\n"
    }
}

fun LogRecord.getTag(tagPrefix: String): String {
    val name = loggerName
    val maxLength = 30
    val tag = tagPrefix + (if (name.length > maxLength) name.substring(name.length - maxLength) else name)
    return tag
}

fun LogRecord.getDate(): String? {
    return Date(millis).formatedBy("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
}

fun Date?.formatedBy(dateFormat: String): String? {
    val date = this
    date ?: return null
    val writeFormat = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault()) //MM в HH:mm
    return writeFormat.format(date)
}

fun LogRecord.getLogCatMessage(): String {
    var message = message

    if (thrown != null) {
        message += Log.getStackTraceString(thrown)
    }
    return message
}

fun Int.getAndroidLevel(): Int {
    return when {
        this >= Level.SEVERE.intValue() -> { // SEVERE
            Log.ERROR
        }
        this >= Level.WARNING.intValue() -> { // WARNING
            Log.WARN
        }
        this >= Level.INFO.intValue() -> { // INFO
            Log.INFO
        }
        else -> {
            Log.DEBUG
        }
    }
}

fun LogRecord.getLogCatLevel(): String {
    return when (level.intValue().getAndroidLevel()) {
        Log.ERROR -> { // SEVERE
            "E/"
        }
        Log.WARN -> { // WARNING
            "W/"
        }
        Log.INFO -> { // INFO
            "I/"
        }
        Log.DEBUG -> {
            "D/"
        }
        else -> {
            "D/"
        }
    }
}

fun getLoggerLevel(level: Int): Level {
    return when (level) {
        Log.ERROR -> { // SEVERE
            Level.SEVERE
        }
        Log.WARN -> { // WARNING
            Level.WARNING
        }
        Log.INFO -> { // INFO
            Level.INFO
        }
        Log.DEBUG -> {
            Level.FINE
        }
        else -> {
            Level.FINEST
        }
    }
}
```

To print all loggers at your app use:

```
Log.e(TAG, printLoggers("before setup"))

 private fun printLoggers(caller: String, printIfEmpty: Boolean = true): String {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        val loggerNames = LogManager.getLogManager().loggerNames
        builder.appendln("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        builder.appendln("printLoggers: $caller")
        while (loggerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            val element = loggerNames.nextElement()
            val logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(element)
            val parentLogger: Logger? = logger.parent
            val handlers = logger.handlers
            val level = logger?.level
            if (!printIfEmpty && handlers.isEmpty()) {
                continue
            }
            val handlersNames = handlers.map {
                val handlerName = it.javaClass.simpleName
                val formatter: Formatter? = it.formatter
                val formatterName = if (formatter is AndroidLogFormatter) {
                    "${formatter.javaClass.simpleName}(${formatter.filePath})"
                } else {
                    formatter?.javaClass?.simpleName
                }
                "$handlerName($formatterName)"
            }
            builder.appendln("level: $level logger: \"$element\" handlers: $handlersNames parentLogger: ${parentLogger?.name}")
        }
        builder.appendln("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        return builder.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Hi. What is the benefit using this "" logger. I see no difference with a custom logger. or Am i missing something ?

Comment: I have tried this and got java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.logging.Logger java.util.logging.Logger.getParent()' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at microlog4android. They have a solution ready to log to a file.

http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

Comment: This seems like a good library, but the documentation is terrible. I simply couldn't figure out how to get it to work and ended up putting something together myself.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: I think it would be nice that you contributed to Microlog4Android instead. FYI: it has the same API as Log4j. Sorry about the bad documentation.

Comment: @Paul Lammertsma How could ANYTHING be good if it's documentation is that bad you can't use it? If you can't get it to work it's crap.

Answer (score 7):

This may be late but hope this may help..
Try this....

```
public void writefile()
    {
        File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myFile = new File(externalStorageDir , "yourfilename.txt");

        if(myFile.exists())
        {
           try
           {

        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fostream); 
        BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(oswriter);   
        bwriter.write("Hi welcome ");
        bwriter.newLine();            
        bwriter.close(); 
        oswriter.close(); 
        fostream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        else
        {
            try {
                myFile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

here `bfwritter.newline` writes your text into the file. And add the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in your manifest file without fail.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a simple, lightweight class (about 260 LoC) that extends the standard android.util.Log implementation with file based logging:
Every log message is logged via android.util.Log and also written to a text file on the device.

You can find it on github:
https://github.com/volkerv/FileLog

Comment: dont you thing we need to ensure file operations are not done on the UI thread. Incase we have huge amount of file logging?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you must have a file handle before opening the stream.  You have a fileOutputStream handle *before* createNewFile() in the else block.  The stream does not create the file if it doesn't exist.

Not really android specific, but that's a lot IO for this purpose.  What if you do many "write" operations one after another?  You will be reading the entire contents and writing the entire contents, taking time, and more importantly, battery life.

I suggest using java.io.RandomAccessFile, seek()'ing to the end, then writeChars() to append.  It will be much cleaner code and likely much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library I've written.
It's very easy to use:

**Add this dependency to your gradle file:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:android-logger:1.0.2'
}
```

**Initialize the library in the Application class:**

```
File logsDirectory = AndroidLogger.getDefaultLogFilesDirectory(this);
    int logFileMaxSizeBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2Mb
    try {
        AndroidLogger.initialize(
                this,
                logsDirectory,
                "Log_File_Name",
                logFileMaxSizeBytes,
                false
                );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Some error happened - most likely there is no free space on the system
    }
```

**This is how you use the library:**

```
AndroidLogger.v("TAG", "Verbose Message");
```

**And this is how to retrieve the logs:**

```
AndroidLogger.processPendingLogsStopAndGetLogFiles(new AndroidLogger.GetFilesCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFiles(File[] logFiles) {
            // get everything you need from these files
            try {
                AndroidLogger.reinitAndroidLogger();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the link to the github page with more information:
https://github.com/danylovolokh/AndroidLogger

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This variant is much shorter

```
try {
    final File path = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DBO_logs5");
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdir();
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "logcat  -d -f " + path + File.separator
                    + "dbo_logcat"
                    + ".txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More short version.

```
public static void AppendLog( Context context, String text){
    File path = context.getExternalFilesDir( "" );
    File logFile = new File( path, "log.txt" );

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_SSS | ");
    String log_line = formatter.format( new java.util.Date() ) + text ;

    try{
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(logFile, true));
        buf.append( log_line );
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
    }
}
```

There is no permission needed. Path to log file: `"Android/data/PACKAGE_NAME/files"`.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the previous versions on log4j dont work now (05/2019). But you can use Hyperlog - I can confirm it works.

1. Add this line to your dependencies & sync project

   ```
   implementation 'com.hypertrack:hyperlog:0.0.10'
   ```
2. Create a new application class (create a new java class and extend Application). Then in the onCreate method add these lines:

   ```
   HyperLog.initialize(this);
   HyperLog.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);

   HyperLog.getDeviceLogsInFile(this);
   ```
3. Change manifest file to have application file defined.

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".AppClass"
       .....
   ```
4. Different ways to log:

   ```
   HyperLog.d(TAG,"debug");
   HyperLog.i(TAG,"information");
   HyperLog.e(TAG,"error");
   HyperLog.v(TAG,"verbose");
   HyperLog.w(TAG,"warning");
   HyperLog.a(TAG,"assert");
   HyperLog.exception(TAG,"exception",throwable);
   ```
5. Find your log files. Navigate to

   ```
   RootFolder/android/data/"appPackageName/LogFiles/
   ```

Comment: I tried this library, in the file generated with 
HyperLog.getDeviceLogsInFile(this); only the last generated log is there

Answer (score -1):

```
    File logFile = new File(filename);
    try { 
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S 
    -f " + logFile);
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    { Basic.Logger("Error Basic", "error "+e); }
```

try this code for Writing Error Log in File