# How to ReadWrite into textfile in android?

Tags: android, file

How to read and write strings in text file in android which is kept in raw folder and also how to clear contents of that file in android?

I have done this way and my "temp.txt" file is in /raw folder. But i am not getting any output in file. Also I am not getting any error for this.

```
       FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("temp", Context.MODE_APPEND);         
        fos.write("Example Text in a file".getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file) one

Answer (score 0):

Try to put file int /asset folder and then do operations