# how can i access logcat file on device

Tags: android, logcat, readfile, android-logcat

How can I access and read the logcat file (at "/system/bin/logcat") from the device, using my application. My phone is not rooted.

Do I need a super user permission?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can read through this code from your application

```
ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
commandLine.add("logcat"); //$NON-NLS-1$
commandLine.add("-d"); //$NON-NLS-1$
ArrayList<String> arguments =
    ((params != null) && (params.length > 0)) ? params[0] : null;
if (null != arguments) {
    commandLine.addAll(arguments);
}

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 1024);

bufferedReader.readLine()
```

Store this bufferedReader in an string or string builder to check your logs

yes you need permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

Comment: Is there any way to execute this without creating a different process ? coz this results are not cleared the next time we execute it ...

Comment: I don't see how `READ_LOGS` permission is related to launching logcat