# How can I search to specified record in database and display all information of this recored in android

Tags: android

I need to search on name of teacher and display all information about it
when user enter teacher name

I have wirrten this code but its given me run time error
this error is:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

this is GetRecord method

```
 public Cursor getRecord(String n1) throws SQLException 
 {
      Cursor mCursor =db.query(true, databaseName, new String[] {facultyc,
                 deparmentc, namec, officeNumberc,Phonec ,emailAddressc,officeHourc},namec + "=" + n1, null, null, null, null, null);
      if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
 }
```

and this  search method, its perfom when user click on search button

```
public void search(){

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getRecord(n);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
        t3.setText(c.getString(2));
        t4.setText(c.getString(3));
        t5.setText(c.getString(4));
        t6.setText(c.getString(5));
        t7.setText(c.getString(6));

    }

    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "this Dr not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}
```

this error appear

> 05-04 13:39:52.856: E/Trace(4001): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: post your stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: 05-04 11:30:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 11:30:58.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):

Comment: @user2324084: this is the only error line you are getting??

Comment: Please provide complete **stacktrace related to the issue** . Follow the [link for your ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608775/2345913)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.Information}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: teachers (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT faculty, deparment, name, officeNumber, phoneNumber, emailAddress, officeHour FROM teachers WHERE name=aaa
2230)

Comment: The table with name **teachers** is yet not created. First create the table with that name by using Create Or replace query and then go with your retrieving code

Comment: DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
i use this to create table