# Setting filter for adapter cause force close on application

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to add a filter to my adapter class (which extends BaseAdapter).

Every thing is working very fine after launching application , But when activity is being re-created (by screen rotation or calling onCreate) the app stops working and makes a force close error

When I remove this Line there is no problem on re-creating activity

```
MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

But debugger shows error is on

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

here is my Main Activity onCreate function:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    new Updator().execute();//Updator is a AsyncTask to update adapter

    EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) 
        {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);//after screen rotation - application stops working when executing this line

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

and this is my filter method in Custom adapter class:

```
private class CustomListFilter extends Filter

{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {   
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = original;
                results.count = original.size();
            }
            else
            {

                final ArrayList<App> nlist = new ArrayList<App>();
                int count = original.size();
                App pkmn;
                String value;
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    pkmn = original.get(i);
                    value = pkmn.getName().toLowerCase();

                    if (value.contains(prefix))
                    {
                        nlist.add(pkmn);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
            }
            return results;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
        {
            mApps = (ArrayList<App>)results.values;

            if (mApps.size() > 0)
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            else
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();


        }

    }
```

Comment: please add the stack trace of the exception from LogCat

Comment: @GilMoshayof I am not so familiar with eclipse , where is stack trace?

Comment: @GilMoshayof please post logcat,to get logcat see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608718/how-to-copy-logcat-output-to-clipboard

Comment: @GiruBhai , are these stack infromation? Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
 <VM does not provide monitor information> 
 FragmentManagerImpl.attachActivity(FragmentActivity, FragmentContainer, Fragment) line: 1867 
 MainActivity(FragmentActivity).onCreate(Bundle) line: 198 
 MainActivity(ActionBarActivity).onCreate(Bundle) line: 97 
 MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 55 
 MainActivity.btnTest(View) line: 264 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line:515

Answer (score 0):

My guess (without see a logcat trace) would be that you are getting a null pointer exception on the problem line:

```
MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

This is either due to `adapter` being null, or the return of `getFilter()` being null.

Make sure you create a non null variable when your Activity is being re-created!

Comment: are these stack infromation? Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) <VM does not provide monitor information> FragmentManagerImpl.attachActivity(FragmentActivity, FragmentContainer, Fragment) line: 1867 MainActivity(FragmentActivity).onCreate(Bundle) line: 198 MainActivity(ActionBarActivity).onCreate(Bundle) line: 97 MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 55 MainActivity.btnTest(View) line: 264 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line:515

Comment: Try (in eclise), Window > Show View > Other ... then Android > LogCat, once the view is open, filter on "error". I think verbose is selected by default, when your exception is thrown, highlight and copy, or press the save icon.

If nothing is showing up, make sure you have select a Device in the "Devices" view