# How to redirect the content in Logcat to file on android?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Recently, I'm developing a android application. I've got a lot of `Log.i` or `Log.e` in my code.

When I test the app on my phone, which is connected to my computer via USB, I can get all the logs under the Logcat. But when my phone not connecting to my computer, I got no idea where the bug comes from because `Log.*` doesn't write logs to file.

Could anyone give my some suggestions on how to **redirect** the `Log.*` to a file with **minimal change to my code**? Thanks a lot!

**p.s.**

I've searched about how to redirect Logcat to file using `adb logcat`. Could anyone tell me how to filter the logs which are corresponding to my current app?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417389/how-can-i-access-logcat-file-on-device

Answer (score 5):

To save LogCat log to file programmatically on your device use for example this code:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/logcat.txt";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-f", filePath, "MyAppTAG:V", "*:S"});
```

`"MyAppTAG:V"` sets the priority level for all tags to Verbose (lowest priority)

`"*:S"` sets the priority level for all tags to "silent"

If you want to save all logcat just put "*:V".

More information about logcat [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Comment: I don't quite understand: You are setting both verbose and then silent. What is the difference between the two last arguments?

Comment: @dthree in this example we set our app tag (e.g. package name) to verbose, and all other logs to silent to ignore them

Comment: Okay. I was testing this, it looks like putting `*:S` after the more specific filter might overwrite that filter and make everything silent. Putting the `*:S` earlier fixed this for me.

Comment: I find some vendor-specific rom will forbid child process to run. Is there some work-around for this problem?