# Create a log file with Log command?

Tags: android, file, report

is it possible write in a file which is written in the Log command line? I mean, i have my code and to see the Log in Eclipse i write something like

```
Log.i("BR", "Log Example");
```

is it possible write the sring `"Log Example"` in a file?
Or, is there a solution to write a report file in which is stored some action of application every 10 minutes?

Comment: Looking for [Write android logcat data to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file) ?

Comment: Do comment if it works. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Right now i'm outside.. When i try i'll write ;)

Comment: Instead of following the previous example, i would extend the Log class and override the log functions. In these fuctions you should add code as Shobbit has informed you.

Answer (score 0):

@**user1281750** The `Log` class uses static methods which technically cannot be overridden, but yes, you could extend the class and create wrappers for these methods.

However, I would suggest using a library like [log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) instead. Or, if my hunch is correct, you may be looking for something like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/).