# extend Android.util.Log to write to file

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

I would like to extend the `android.util.Log` class to also write to a log file in internal storage of the device, preferrably also for specific `TAGS`.

I currently have an implementation:

```
public class CustomLogger{

private final static Logger fileLog = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class);
private Context context;

public CustomLogger(Context c){
    this.context = c;

    final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
    logConfigurator.setFileName(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "myApp.log");
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
    logConfigurator.configure();
}

public void i(String TAG, String message){

    // Printing the message to LogCat console
    Log.i(TAG, message);

    // Write the log message to the file
    fileLog.info(TAG+": "+message);
}

public void d(String TAG, String message){
    Log.d(TAG, message);
    fileLog.debug(TAG+": "+message);
  }
 }
```

As you can see this custom logger logs both to a log file on the internal storage (using the `android-logging-log4j` library) and through the `android.util.Log` class. 
However i would like the standard log entries from the `android.util.Log` class in my log file, and if possible only certain (custom) `TAGS`.

Anybody has an example or any good tips on how to reach this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write android logcat data to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 7):

You can read log cat programmatically and store into text file or you send it wherever you want.

Below is the detailed article I have written for same:

[Read & Store Log-cat Programmatically in Android](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/07/read-store-log-cat-programmatically-in.html)

And for reading the logcat here is sample code:

```
public class LogTest extends Activity {
 
    private StringBuilder log;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
 
            log=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line);
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(log.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }       
 
        //convert log to string
        final String logString = new String(log.toString());
 
        //create text file in SDCard
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");

        try {  
            //to write logcat in text file
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

            // Write the string to the file
            osw.write(logString);            
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So there is much shorter variant

```
try {
    final File path = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DBO_logs5");
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdir();
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "logcat  -d -f " + path + File.separator
                    + "dbo_logcat"
                    + ".txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to exec logcat? I mean, can you expect it to be guaranteed available? Does your app need certain permissions?