# Not able to write logcat output to a file within my app

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I am working on Android app in which I am trying to output the contents of logcat into a file on the sdcard.

I am aware of the fact that

- From JellyBean 3P apps do not have access to system logs. However, I believe using logcat within my app, outputs atleast the log messages
  put out by my app.
- Using WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest file.

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  try {
    //Code 1 - Seems like an app hang. Nothing shown.
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f /sdcard/mylog");

    //Code 2 - This works however if I run this alone, without the above. 
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/sdcard/mylog");
    writer.append("test");
    writer.close();
  }
    catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

I am testing my app on a device running kitkat.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If it helps. You can read text at bottom at this link http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html.
You can try to route output during phone or tablet lifecycle. But I am not sure about permissions needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command logcat it doesn't stop, it keeps running unless you ask it stop (Ctrl + C). You need to use logcat dump so that it dumps the logcat and stops.

```
logcat -d
```

This will dump the current contents of the logcat and finish once done.

Edit:

This wont work from the devise without root permissions anymore, starting from Jellybean.

Comment: yes i tried that too. Using "logcat -d -f /sdcard/mylog" didn't seem to be helpful as well.

Comment: Oh, seems like it wont work from the device side anymore. You need root permission to be able to use logcat command now.

Comment: Did you set android.permission.READ_LOGS permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Hiemanshu, can you please quote the source where you found that info? busylee, yes I did.

Comment: @Hiemanshu, If it needs root permision to read log file on phone, how adb did it? I think it isn't right.

Comment: You can find the source here:  http://nolanlawson.com/2012/09/02/catlog-jives-with-jelly-bean-goes-open-source/

Also adb has special permissions that individual apps dont.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f");

            Log.d("TAG", "my test phrase");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/sdcard/mylog");

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fw.append(line);
            }

            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

This works for me. Hope it helps.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175347/2156937)