# Write app errors log to file

Tags: android, android-log

I start test my app in many devices and I want read error logs from this devices. How can I write **my application** errors messages to file? It would be convenient if I could write them to a file and then sent to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write android logcat data to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file)

Comment: I want write **only** _my application_ errors

Comment: Use the same code as given in the above link. Try adding the `-s` flag with your app's tagname like so: `logcat -d -s "TAGNAME"`