# Collecting all log data of my android app

Tags: android, android-logcat, acra

I am familiar with collecting crash reports using ACRA library.

Is it possible collecting all logs of my Android app in a remote device, **not** only crash logs?

For instance, when tester is testing my app, all those logs should be updated to my system (e.g. by mail, or any way that lets me analyze the log on my system).

Is there any third party library for that, or can we get it from Android native?

Comment: Mean, from your application only?

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes.While running app in IDE we get logs, like those ,logs of my app we need.

Comment: You can achieve this by your own code.

Comment: @NigamPatro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file

Comment: @NigamPatro Please confirm that we can obtain only system level logs? Can't we get our own logs?

Comment: Mean, I didn't understood.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98660/discussion-between-karthikeyan-ve-and-nigam-patro).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 4.1 the only app which can access your logs is your own app. That means you have to integrate this functionality in your app.

You can use ACRA to do that: just call `ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(null)` periodically (e.g. every time your app exits).