# how to generate local(mobile phone) log text file

Tags: android

In order to trace log/what happen in android studio, i usually use log.i
but now i having a problem

which is, when i try to connect to internet (load my php) the app crash.
BUT it wont crash during my android virtual device, it ONLY crash when i install and run on my mobile phone.

the log.i, didnt log down any error at virtual device, but after installing to phone, how i can see the log.i? or is there a way to log down what when wrong on my mobile phone.

so what is the way to generate a log file so i can see what when wrong.

i hope you guys understand my english....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write android logcat data to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take a look at [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/). It's a free service that let's you track your crashes remotely.

Comment: sound good, but #bartek, i visited the website and i dont know how to use it, i didnt find and apk or downloadable for me to download and install....

Comment: The installation of Crashlytics is as straightforward as it can really be. You need to show some initiative. From the linked page: "To get Crashlytics, just download Fabric and install the Crashlytics Kit."

Comment: thanks #bartek, i start learning how to use it, and yes, i found the crashing bug, thank you very much