# How to display very long text (like book) in text view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to display very long text from book in view with scroll. But when I load text in standart WebView or TextView I have OutOfMemoryException. So maybe view have to dynamic load data (part of text) from file. How do it?

Comment: Please show source and stack trace

Comment: This should be a really big amount of text to get you an OutOfMemoryException..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create a buffer to store your text temporarily

you might find something useful here

[Android Writing Logs to text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file)