# log file for errors?

Tags: android, aide-ide

I am developing an Android-App with "Aide".Aide is an app for developing android apps with android devices. When i start the app, i have created, i get an error like "the app has aborted unfortunately". how can i resolve what happened wrong ? is there a log-file where i can see the stack trace ? is ist possible that everytime an error happens a dialog apperas with the stack trace instead of the message "the app has aborted" ? thanks for everybody who can help me.

Greets

Arne

Answer (score 2):

If you want to observe the stack trace, all you need is a LogCat reader, like [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en), for instance.  Note that if your device is Jelly Bean of higher, you'll need root permissions to read the logs.

EDIT:
Further research indicates that there is a LogCat reader built into AIDE.  The root permission issue still applies.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Aide, but the concept will be the same. You need to be able to debug your app on your phone via your IDE. As an example in Eclipse I would connect my phone via usb and in Eclipse it then shows up as an Android Device in AVD. I then run my App in Debug mode on my phone and all your error output will be in Logcat. Otherwise you will have to code debug logic into your app so that it writes it's own logging onto your fs on you phone.

Comment: This ide runs on the phone/tablet... no usb needed so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Android SDK installed (I guess it's the case), then you can use the `adb` utility to access the log :

```
adb logcat
```

This will show you stacktrace in case of error, and many very other useful informations.

Comment: Hi. I tried it with an App called "Terminal Emulator".the daemon starts and waits for a device. when my app is crashing no error is shown on the terminal

Answer (score -1):

You got 3 options:

1. Upgrade into a stable Pro version to use the working LogCat on AIDE
2. Use USB debugging as mentioned by apesa
3. Use following function to log to local file:

   public void appendLog(String text)
   // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209739/8800831
   {
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
   try
   {
   logFile.createNewFile();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   try
   {
   //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
   BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
   buf.append(text);
   buf.newLine();
   buf. flush();
   buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }

Use it like this:

```
try{
       // your code goes here
}catch (Exception e){
       appendLog(e);
}
```

You need to add permission for writing_external_storage in Manifest.