# Arraylist of cutom class to save as a txt file

Tags: android, file

I have an arraylist of cutom class like below:

```
public class Struct
{    
    String Name = "";  
    String Password = "";  
    String id = "";  
}
```

and i am using this as an array like below:

```
ArrayList<Struct> list = new ArrayList<Struct>();
```

I have added entries in the array list but now i tried to save it as a txt file on android but it give me **Serializable Exception**

Anybody can help me in this regard that how can i save this array list as a file ??

Comment: change to this line..public class Struct implements Serializable

Comment: @kalyanpvs... thanks man it worked :)... But how can i see my file now in file explorer?

Comment: i didn't get u??Where you want to see your file.

Comment: @Kalyanpvs.. in the eclipse file explorer..can i see it?

Comment: What is the path of your file??

Comment: @kalyanpvs..i did not set any path

Comment: By default it will saved in your Application project package check there once..

Comment: this link may usefull to you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file?rq=1