# Logs not shown in android device

Tags: android, logcat

I am a beginner in Android Development. When I run  my app in emulator ,i can see logs of my app in Logcat. But when I run the same app in android device, No logs filed in Catlog app. Can anyone tell me what i have missed here?

Comment: select the android device from `DDMS` perspective. Then it will show the logs.

Comment: @Jamal is referring to an app apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, apps can only read their own logs starting from 4.1 on an unrooted device:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34792

Comment: This is only for doing it programmatically (read logs from other apps with an app), you can still see the logs of other apps in the logcat >4.1.

Comment: @Jamal is referring to an app: `No logs filed in Catlog app`. I guess it's this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

Comment: @FD_: Thanks for the reply. yes, you are correct. The logs are not filed in the Catlog app downloaded from "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat". So is there any way to trace the logs?
Actually my client is testing the app. But it crashed often. So how can I get the logs from client's device?

Comment: Just write a simple helper class that appends log lines to a text file. Soemthing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209739/1691231. That's what I did for one of my projects.