# Is it possible to log app while not connected to eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging

So the problem is, that I have made application which runs well for about one week and then starts to fail. Is it possible to somehow log the application while not connected to eclipse? And when it starts to fail, connect the device to eclipse and see the log?

Comment: What do you mean by "Starts to fail"?

Comment: Just write to a text file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to save the log, Write it to the text file as Huxley told. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file) is the link clearly telling you about how to save the log file. if you only want to see the log you can see that in `Terminal` with the help of shell command.

Move the directory path to Platform-tools as like this

```
system6@system6:~/android-sdks/platform-tools$
```

if you are using `linux`, Use `./adb logcat` to view the logs. if windows `adb logcat` will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **adb logcat** for the issue. For example it would be like this in your shell after the application fails:

```
adb logcat -s "TAG"
```

or like this (if you want to save log somewhere)

```
adb logcat -s "TAG" >> Log.txt
```

[Android developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) has full help on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the Logger with your own class that saves messages into a file on your SD card or the internal storage.