# Official recommendation on retrieving "Log" records

Tags: android, logcat

Why there is no official recommendation on how to retrieve records of Log class? I know that "Log" is:

```
    ` Log is a logging class that you can utilize in your code to print out messages to the LogCat.
```

Also:

```
    ` You can use LogCat from within DDMS or call it on an ADB shell.
```

But how can we save these records in a file?

I'm aware of a bunch of "unofficial" approaches to achieve that, but no where in android's documentation are they mentioned (hence the name "unofficial")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file

Comment: Where in OFFICIAL documentation are they mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there is no official recommendation on how to retrieve records of Log class?

Because that is not supported. Quoting Dianne Hackborn:

> Keep in mind that access to the logs has never been part of the SDK, and is still not part of the SDK

(from [this android-developers thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang) discussing how you cannot hold the `READ_LOGS` permission anymore)

> But how can we save these records in a file?

Write them to a file yourself, at the point in time when you are doing the logging. For example, you could write your own wrapper that you use instead of `Log.e()` and stuff directly, that writes to a file instead of, or in addition to, LogCat. IIRC, people have created LogCat support for various Java logging frameworks as well.