# Android logs while not connected to Logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

Does android save any logs when not plugged in development mode and using log cat?

Can app crashes be detected when device is not in debug mode?

Comment: You can create your own ExceptionHandler class and write logs to a file on SDCard. You can get more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I obtain crash-data from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

use this to catch error

Comment: add this in your application class