# Save Logcat from Android app to txt file

Tags: android, logging, save, logcat, android-logcat

I'm trying to get all my logcat, which I see in `Android Studio` (like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/sseEr.png), to save as a `txt file` directly on my device.

What I've tryed so far is this code in the `onCreate`:

```
File logFile = new File(LogcatDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/log.txt" );
try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -c");
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -f " + logFile + " *:S MyActivity_BUT_WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE");
}
catch ( IOException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

and in the `manifest file`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

I intentionally did a parse Error like

```
long test = Long.parseLong("z");
```

but there was actually only this in the `log.txt`:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
```

Does anyone know, what I have to code, that I get the whole logcat?

Comment: Note that `READ_LOGS` is unavailable to ordinary Android SDK apps on Android 4.1 and higher: https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html

Comment: Try to not call the "logcat -c" since that flushes it

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file

Comment: @ivan i don't call `logcat -c ` again so i guess i'm not deleting the file

Comment: @bhiku what these methods do, is writing manually into a file, but i wanna have the normal logcat in to a file ... so not by `appendToLog(String)` but by default the whole logcat

Comment: my best guess is that since you execute logcat -c first it flushes the log and then it saves it, do a test with 
Log.w("Before the flush","-c")
Log.w("After the flush","-f")
and see what happens that may be it

Comment: @ivan well now i did this:

`Log.w("before","-c");

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -c");


Log.w("After the flush","-f");``

But actually it's still the same in the `log.txt`

It's the same if i go `System.err.print("err");`

Comment: try executing: logcat -d -f

Comment: @ivan doesn't effect anything :/ neither if I do `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -d -f");` nor if I do `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -d -f " + logFile + " *:S .main");`

Comment: @Pixel_95 ill try to do some tests around to see if i get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me it saves it in the main storage with this code:

```
Log.w("before","Logcat save");
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -f " + "/storage/emulated/0/"+"Logging.txt");
}catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No prob :D @Pixel_95

Comment: @ivan does this not require <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> ?

Comment: Oh according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WDDgoxvQsrQ#t=1369s) by google. JellyBean and up allows without a permission to read system log for your own app. I wish this statement was thrown around a lot more.

Comment: Something to note: the exec command doesn't automatically create a directory for anyone that wanted to do ".../logs/log.txt", you'll have to create it beforehand.