# Are DDMS logs reliable?

Tags: android, android-logcat, ddms

I have eight different services running on my Android tab which are sending data, receiving data, sending broadcast data and receiving broadcast data with each other at high frequency speed. By this i assure each service has four specific funtionalities.

I have tagged all four of these functionalities with a TAG like

```
TAG_SERVICE1_SEND
TAG_SERVICE1_BROADCAST
TAG_SERVICE1_RECEIVE
TAG_SERVICE1_RECEIVEBROADCAST
```

I have written python utility which searches each of TAG data and make seperate log files out of it.

```
adb -s deviceId logcat | find \ TAG_SERVICE1_RECEIVE > C:\\STRESS\\TAG_SERVICE1_RECEIVE.txt
```

Now, I have a problem only at receiving side since as super high frequency when data is received all of the data are not logged on my log file. I have assigned sequence to each data byte sent but on receving side all data are not received.

I will be too fool to blame DDMS but i just want the assurance from you experts. Whether this condition could cause an data logging problem from DDMS side.

Comment: Why not to use custom logger to log directly in file? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13479675/903469

Comment: Yeas, this is the best way but i can't use this since my only problem is that the android app i am developing are test apk's and data fills upto 1GB or more while stress testing. I don't want to take chance for app crash which is to run for hours