# Android saving logs on server/ database every run for crash report?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an android app. I noticed a very rare error which Leeds to a crash of my app. Unfortunately, I had my smartphone never connected to my PC when it occurred. So, is there a way to automatically save all logs to server/ database (and especially the thrown **run time exceptions**). The error data should be overwritten on every start of my app, so that it contains only the logs of the last run... How can I achieve that?

Thanks 
Mahak Singhvi

Comment: Here is a post that talks about your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file

Answer (score 0):

## Logcat

You can use Logcat. It is a command-line tool that dumps a log of system messages, stack traces and messages that you have written from your app with the Log class.

You can run logcat as an adb command (or directly in a shell prompt).

```
adb logcat
```

Logcat can also write directly to a file:

```
public static void backupLogcatToFile(Context context) {    
  String fileName = "logcat_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
  File outputFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

## OpenSource projects

The project [CatSaver](https://github.com/kennytm/CatSaver) is an Android service that automatically saves logcat. It provides an HTTP server that allows you to save and download logcat data without adb-connecting to the device.

If you need to collect crash log after the app is released, you can use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra).