# Write the logcat in a txt file on a phone application

Tags: android, debugging, logging, usb, adb

I have an application that's crashing on the real device but working fine on the emulated device. I need to see what errors I'm getting on the real device, that's why I need to write the logcat into a file or at least to manually add logs in the procedures.

I've tried the USB debugging mode but somehow my PC won't detect any phone through USB even though I have installed several updates and USB drivers.

Comment: All you need is Firebase crashlytics https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file) . But with some changes:

```
public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"log.txt");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new     FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
    }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Also, do not forget that since we are writing files in the android file system, we need to request permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And also, just for avoid errors, include this:

```
<application
    ....
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
</application>
```

Finally, if you are running in android version >=6.0, we recommend to request run time permission, because, even if these are accepted from the application settings it will not work.

How to request runtime permission -> https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

or you can use a library like a [dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

The log.txt is in the download folder of your android device